# SEO: publish article on multiple platforms, or just link?

Tags: seo, content, social-media

If I have my own blog and I make posts there, it is better if I go to my social profiles (Google+, Tumblr, Facebook, Pinterest, etc.) and I copy/paste the same content of that post, or it is better if I just put there a link with a small excerpt to tease the user to click on the link to read the full story? Which strategy is better, or maybe there is a third better strategy that I didn't mention here?

How can I improve my authorship rank using social media?

Comment: Google monitors social profiles but it doesn't give the same weight as you would think, its just an indicator and adds a lot to the trust factor and even then Google are vague how it completely works. Generally its better to keep the message sort, its personal choice to keep it unique or duplicated, many webmasters use API's to mass publish their news to all the social networks they are on. But with this said you shouldn't be seeing social media as a SEO tool, its extra ways of driving traffic to your site directly without the need of the search engines.

Comment: Authorship as far as I know and correct me if I'm wrong has not be introduced as a true ranking factor as of yet, this opens a whole can of worms for paying people to write for their site because they have good authorship rankings and this could be completely abused, again I could be wrong but I thought Google was still in process of decending this, unless I mistaken the question.

Comment: Author rank exists and is being used.  To what extent it determines things is, of course, completely unknowable.  Best guesses right now is it factors into the overall "trust" aspect of the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and I copy/paste the same content of that post, or it is better if I just put there a link with a small excerpt to tease the user to click on the link to read the full story?

The latter.  So very much the latter.  You want social media entries to be short and to the point using eye-catching words and images.  Your long form content should be uniquely available on your web site with appropriate social sharing buttons prominently visible.  The more your content is shared, liked, retweeted, pinned and +1'd the better your authorship rank will be.  Make sure you have the rel=author meta tag set to your Google+ account and added to all pages of your blog.

Comment: There is also the problem with duplicate content. Although search engines normally get it correct in figuring out the original source of the article, I have seen it many times where content on a facebook, Google + page, etc, out rank the original article on the main website.

Comment: @moobot Just anecdotally: The only time I have ever seen a "social" site outperform a blog is if the content is duped on Google+ and it's hardly a stretch to figure out why that happens.  Facebook is not really oriented towards long-form posting and the other social forms even less so.  Therefore, i feel that, for the most part, duplicating content isn't a big worry. One should take advantage of Google+ to publish alternate content from time to time though...